# How does this numerical integral approximation stack up against the fastest converging Numerical Integration techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I came up with a **numerical integration approximation** sometime 2005 or so.

It employs **Simpson's rule** in computing the error incurred in computing the numerical integral of a function, say `f(x)` using a **polynomial** of best fit.

**(DISCLAIMER: I do not know if anyone has come up with this formula before. I would like to know, please)**

My technique computes the polynomial using a simple and I believe well known method...breaking up the curve into small units and finding the y values along those points.

Then solving for the coefficients of the resulting polynomial using a **matrix** method.

So if we wish to approximate `y=sin(x)`, for example: say with a **polynomial** of degree `n = 5`,

between `x = 1` and `x = 3`.

Then we would have:

```
dx = (3 - 1)/5; say dx = 0.4;
```

So `x1 = 1, x2 = 1.4, x3 = 1.8, x4 = 2.2, x5 = 2.6, x6 = 3.`

So the approximating polynomial gives:

```
 h(1.0) = sin(1)   = a0 + 1.0.a1 + 1.02.a2 + 1.03.a3 + 1.04.a4 + 1.05.a5 
 h(1.4) = sin(1.4) = a0 + 1.4.a1 + 1.42.a2 + 1.43.a3 + 1.44.a4 + 1.45.a5
 h(1.8) = sin(1.8) = a0 + 1.8.a1 + 1.82.a2 + 1.83.a3 + 1.84.a4 + 1.85.a5
 h(2.2) = sin(2.2) = a0 + 2.2.a1 + 2.22.a2 + 2.23.a3 + 2.24.a4 + 2.25.a5
 h(2.6) = sin(2.6) = a0 + 2.6.a1 + 2.62.a2 + 2.63.a3 + 2.64.a4 + 2.65.a5
 h(3.0) = sin(3.0) = a0 + 3.0.a1 + 3.02.a2 + 3.03.a3 + 3.04.a4 + 3.05.a5
```

This gives the polynomial:

`h(x) = 0.05621527890686895 + 0.8070522394224585.x + 0.2659311952212848.x2 - 0.35406795117551315.x3 + 0.0696942723181288.x4 - 0.003354049885331352.x5`

Then I compute the integral using **polynomial integration** of `h(x)`, which is simple enough.

I then use **Simpson's rule** to estimate the error incurred in computing the integral, using the approximation:

**A<sub>e</sub>** = `S(f(x)) - S(h(x))`.

Where `S(f(x))` is **Simpson's approximation** for `f(x)` and `S(h(x))` is **Simpson's** approximation for `h(x)`.

By adding this error area to `h(x)` and summing all along the path, I get
    [this formula](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pqWkWbugAKY/V6K06dAtVrI/AAAAAAAAAOA/KACIYHHDauMJ_DIdPJVanrKh411DzW9VQCLcB/s640/EARI_Integral_f%2528x%2529_formula.jpg)

**[Please check out a detailed coverage of the technique here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sguk.jpg)**, if more detail is needed, as I dont want the question to spiral out of control.

I believe that this technique will always converge faster than Simpson's rule or the Polynomial approximation that I used. (even though it will always be more complex to program or use.)
**Is this true?** If not, under what circumstances will it not be true?

Also, how does this technique match up against **Gaussian quadrature** and other macho-techniques accepted as best practices today?

Finally, I believe that any kind of polynomial approximation can be used to replace the type I used.

Is this true? what better polynomial approximations are there that can effectively replace the one I used in the formula?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How *exactly* does your method differ from a Newton-Cotes method? High order Newton-Cotes methods have long been recognized as being bad for a variety of reasons. The main one is simply that the evenly-spaced polynomial interpolant of a continuous function $f$ doesn't even converge to $f$ in general. Nor does it even if you assume $f$ is smooth.

Comment: As for your "correction", this is very similar in spirit to Richardson extrapolation, which in the case of integration rules is called Romberg integration.

Comment: I believe any polynomial approximation can be used. But for this particular one that I am using. I want to know if the error estimate that I used is efficient enough.I used Simpson's rule to estimate the error in computation using the polynomial method.  I have tested it on many integrals and I have seen it increase the accuracy a lot. Between polynomial degrees 5 and 10, for many examples the integral, converges fast it seems. For y=sin(x) between x =1 and x=3, using a polynomial of order 5, this technique gives:1.5302948297254457. Real value is -1.5302948024685852

 of -1.5302948024685852

Comment: Okay..."Similar in spirit"? Are they absolutely the same? I mean the Romberg integration part. as in will they give exactly same results if applied to the same problems?

Comment: No, they're not quite the same, in fact your technique is not even guaranteed to improve the order of the original method. But the idea is the same: do some further calculation to get the "leading order term" of the error and then add that back in to hopefully reduce the error.

Comment: Also, testing with examples like $\sin(x)$ may give you artificially good results, for subtle reasons that get explored in numerical analysis. Try it with the function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ on the interval $[-10,10]$. You may actually get a good result in the end, but notice how large $S(f(x))-S(h(x))$ is.

Comment: If you have the time, can you give me some figures using Romberg Integration for the example I used here..if its closer to the real answer, please put up an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Romberg integration is just a method for coming up with a higher order integration method starting from a lower order one. For example, let's denote the trapezoidal rule with step size $h$ by $T_1(h)$. Let's denote the true integral of a sufficiently smooth function $f$ by $I(h)$. This method has order $2$, meaning $T_1(h)=I(h)+c_1 h^2$ plus higher order terms, where $c_1$ is some constant. As a consequence, $T_2(h):=\frac{4T_1(h/2)-T_1(h)}{3}$ is a higher order method. As it happens $T_2$ is the Simpson rule.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with discontinuities in the function?

Comment: You can now continue: Simpson has order $4$ so $T_3(h):=\frac{16T_2(h/2)-T_2(h)}{15}$ has an even higher order. Eventually, these methods become bad, because these "hidden constants" tend to become large, or because your integrand doesn't have enough regularity to continue the expansion any further, or because of floating point arithmetic (these methods tend to subtract nearly equal numbers). In fact, $T_3$ is already not used by itself. It is however used for adaptive quadrature methods (using the Simpson rule with a step size $h$ that depends on $x$, using $T_3$ to estimate the error).

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with discontinuities...at least not on the real axis. $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is a famous example of a smooth function which simply can't be well-approximated on a sufficiently large interval symmetric about zero by a uniformly sampled interpolating polynomial. This is called "Runge's phenomenon", and it is closely related to the fact that this function has a pole at $x=i$ in the complex plane. $\sin(x)$ has no such poles and so you observe better results.

Comment: Can you post an answer, so I can accept....hmmm, I should be hanging my math boots then. There goes the last of my so-called derivations during my math hobbyist years when I was a youngster

Comment: I'm not sure how to cook up a clean answer, there are so many little bits to talk about here. I'd suggest just picking up a graduate numerical analysis text like Atkinson or something, they inevitably have a huge quadrature chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are integrating a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) on some evenly-spaced samples $(x_i,f(x_i))$ of the function. With $n$ points, your technique integrates polynomials of up to $(n-1)$th order exactly.

This is not optimal: by cleverly (and non-uniformly) choosing the locations of the sampling points $x_i$, an $(2n+1)$th order accurate integration can be done using only $n$ points. See [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature).

Comment: You said nothing about the whole technique, just the polynomial. The formula takes the sum of error areas involved in computing the integral using a polynomial integration method and adds them to the final answer. How fast does this method converge towards the answer compared to other methods.